# Most compact way to deep copy double[][] with Java 8

Tags: java-8

Wondering what the most compact way to deep copy a double[][] array is in Java 8?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one-liner (pretty ugly though):

```
double[][] d = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
double[][] e = Arrays.stream(d).map(double[]::clone).toArray(double[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(e));
// [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Alternate (fallback) solution:

```
double[][] e = Arrays.stream(d).map(a -> (double[])a.clone()).toArray(double[][]::new);
```

Comment: Sweet - that's perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm - Getting an error: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method map(Function<? super double[],? extends R>) in the type Stream<double[]> is not applicable for the arguments (double[]::clone) ArrayMatrix.java /firefly-math-linear-real/src/main/java/com/fireflysemantics/math/linear/matrix line 78 Java Problem

Comment: @user1684269 Which version of java do you use? It compiles and runs for me in eclipse luna and works well compiled from command line (`java, javac: 1.8.0_66`)

Comment: Yes - It's strange - I'm running the same java version as you and I created a really simple test and when I run it I still get:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method map(Function<? super double[],? extends R>) in the type Stream<double[]> is not applicable for the arguments (double[]::clone)
 The type of clone() from the type Object is Object, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: R

 at com.fireflysemantics.math.exception.test.main(test.java:10)

Comment: I'm running in Eclipse Mars

Comment: OK - I tried the first one outside of Eclipse and it works fine.  Must be a JDT issue.

Comment: No need for `new double[][]`. Just initialize your array as `double[][] d={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};`…

Comment: For the records: Eclipse had a regression concerning `double[]::clone` introduced in Mars, fixed in HEAD, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/485593